# Running SQL queries on a local SQL file

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

I have a SQL file opened in VS Code with `mssql` extension on, I want to run a query on it but they keep prompting me to create a connection profile. I tried to enter information to create one but it didn't work (`ECONNREFUSED` error).

I'm new to SQL Server and VS Code; I found out that I need to create a local SQL Server first on my machine, then I can create a database on it and then I can run scripts against it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userInfo 
(
    `name` VARCHAR(188) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `age` INT,
    `country` VARCHAR(44) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `employment` VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `fashion` INT,
    `art` INT,
    `technologie` INT,
    `food` INT,
    `drink` INT,
    `travel` INT,
    `health` INT,
    `sport` INT,
    `movie` INT,
    `politique` INT,
    `like_fashion` INT,
    `like_art` INT,
    `like_technologie` INT,
    `like_food` INT,
    `like_drink` INT,
    `like_travel` INT,
    `like_health` INT,
    `like_sport` INT,
    `like_movie` INT,
    `like_politique` INT,
    `msg_fashion` INT,
    `msg_art` INT,
    `msg_technologie` INT,
    `msg_food` INT,
    `msg_drink` INT,
    `msg_travel` INT,
    `msg_health` INT,
    `msg_sport` INT,
    `msg_movie` INT,
    `msg_politique` VARCHAR(4) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO userInfo VALUES
```

I expect to have an table output with results

Comment: I am voting to close this question. We need significantly more information. Have you installed `SQL Server` on your computer? Is it up and running? Have you connected `VSCode` to it? There is not enough information for us to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, Given that you are new to Sql Server, my advice would be to find a good tutorial or class and go through it. It is tempting to just jump into the technology and start working, but that will lead to a lot of confusion and frustration. This tutorial for example seems to cover a lot of the basic. Hope it helps: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net

Comment: First of all - drop all those backticks (`) from your SQL - that's not the way to do it in SQL Server. Also: SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8 - so all those "CHARACTER SET" statements also need to be stripped away. But seriously: you **really** need to study a Beginner's SQL Server 101 tutorial first, before going at it running scripts and creating tables.....

Comment: ok thank you all , i will use the tutorial below it has the right steps to follow , i had a theory class but with nothing applicable.